# If $f(x)$ has $k$ critical points and has degree $n$, show that $n-k$ is odd

Tags: calculus, polynomials

> Assume a polynomial of degree $n$ has precisely $k$ critical points and $f''(x) \neq 0$ for all critical points $x$. Show that $n-k$ is odd.

If $f''(x) \neq 0$ for all critical values $x$, then that must mean there aren't any infection points that are also critical values. In other words, if $f'(x) = 0$, then $f''(x) \neq 0$. How do I write this algebraically as an equation?

Comment: Why is $f$ strictly concave or convex? What's wrong with a general cubic that has two criticals, and an inflection point in between them?

Comment: @AlfredYerger Hmm, I misread that as $f''(x) \neq 0 $ for all $x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $P$ be the polynomial, $x_1,...,x_k$ the critical points, you can write $P'(x)=(x-x_1)..(x-x_k)q(x)$, the polynomial $q$ does not have a zero so its degree is even. By integrating, you obtain the result.

Comment: What is $q(x)$ here?

Comment: you divide $p'$ by $(x-x_1)...(x-x_k)$, the result is $q(x)$

Comment: How are you sure that $P''(x) \neq 0$ for $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$?

Comment: because they are critical points

Comment: What I mean to say is how did you take that condition into account? Or you didn't really need to?